# Is the product group of finitely many copies of the multiplicative group of positive real numbers a reductive group?

Tags: group-theory, real-numbers, moduli-space, reductive-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

Let G be the multiplicative group of positive real numbers. Is the finite product group $G \times \cdots \times G$ reductive?

I am trying to construct the moduli space for some quiver representations and the properties I am looking for are forcing me to look at the action of this particular group. So if this group is reductive then we can construct the moduli space by GIT. If not, what else can be done to construct the moduli space?

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if moduli spaces can be constructed for this particular group acting on a variety?

Comment: It is the multiplicative group $\Bbb G_m$, which is reductive, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group). So not the additive group. In your case, the additive group of real numbers is NOT reductive.

Comment: I mean the multiplicative group of POSITIVE real numbers, which is isomorphic to the additive group of real numbers. Is it reductive?

Comment: No, it is not reductive. I don't know whether you can extend the group action to the multiplicative group $\Bbb R^{\times}$?

Comment: The action can be extended, yes. But it will not preserve the properties I want.